# Zend Framework 1.12 + Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.2

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework

Is there any workaround to decorate ZF 1.12 forms with bootstrap >= 3.0.0 ? I tried [Bootstrap-Zend-Framework](https://github.com/komola/Bootstrap-Zend-Framework) and [EasyBib](https://github.com/easybib/EasyBib_Form_Decorator). None of them work properly. I think they both generate bootstrap 2 forms.

If there is no ready to use decorator or modules, I would like to modify on of old codes or write my own decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no Bootstrap3 decorators for ZF1. I have created [fork of EasyBib](https://github.com/peterslivka/EasyBib_Form_Decorator/tree/bootstrap3), but it's far from finished. Maybe you will find it useful, I'll update it occasionally.